# How to import CDN stylesheet link into Cypress component test runner

Tags: vue.js, cypress, vue-cli, cypress-component-test-runner

I have a vue-cli project. I've set successfully the cypress component test runner using the official documentation: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/introduction. Now I have a problem using icon fonts that are delivered in my app through CDN links (namely fontawesome and mdi icons), included in my index.html. One of these links, for ex.:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" />
```

Since the component test runner does not load the `index.html`, the icons are missing and some functionalities cannot be tested. And I haven't found a place were I can include these links (Importing them in every `<component>.vue` file is not a solution).

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

NB: I don't want to install npm packages of those frameworks. I need to use the CDN delivered versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cypress wraps the vue-test-utils `mount()` function, which has an [attachTo](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#attachto) option, so this is how you can add the CDN link into the test

**HelloWorld.spec.ts**

```js
import { mount } from '@cypress/vue'
import HelloWorld from './HelloWorld.vue'

describe('HelloWorld', () => {
  it('renders a message', () => {
    const msg = 'Hello Cypress Component Testing!'

    // This elem is to attach the component to document 
    const elem = document.createElement('div')
    if (document.body) {
      document.body.appendChild(elem)
    }

    // Attach the CDN link to document
    const linkElem = document.createElement('link');
    linkElem.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    linkElem.setAttribute('href', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css');
    if (document.head) {
      document.head.appendChild(linkElem)
    }

    mount(HelloWorld, {
      propsData: {
        msg
      },
      attachTo: elem
    })

    cy.get('i').should('be.visible');             // fails if the CDN link is omitted

  })
})
```

I'm not sure how the icons contribute to the test logic, but you can verify they are loaded by `cy.get('i').should('be.visible')`.

If not loaded (comment out `linkElem` above) the test fails with

> This element <i.mdi.mdi-account> is not visible
> because it has an effective width and height of: 0 x 0 pixels.

**HelloWorld.vue template with icon**

```html
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1><i class="mdi mdi-account"></i> {{ msg }}</h1>
```

---

BTW I couldn't get the example in the docs working, I had to use [vue-cypress-template](https://github.com/lmiller1990/vue-cypress-template)

Ref [Getting Started with Cypress Component Testing (Vue 2/3) - Apr 06 2021 • Lachlan Miller](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2021/04/06/getting-start-with-cypress-component-testing-vue-2-3/)

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. I needed the icons because I'm using Vuetify and their components rely on mdi icons, and when missing the click events, for ex, cannot be triggered on respective elements. Thanks!